# I want to print angular component with page break using CTRL + P

Tags: html, angular, printing, components, page-break

I tried like below

project structure

[image: structure]

Job summary component need to be printed

HTML

```
<div>
  <div>first page</div>
  <div class="page-break"></div>
  <div>second page</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
@media print {
  .page-break { page-break-before: always; } 
}
```

the result only shows the first page

[image: result]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works fine for me.

[image]

Please make sure that you added your css file to your component's `styleUrls` array.

E.g: `styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]`

Check demo at [Stackbtitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mr8gi7?file=src/app/app.component.html). Click **Open in New Window** to check.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you do not have display: flex in your script. if yes then add a wrapper to it and give the same class. or move appcomponent css classes to global styles.css

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).